# Draw a rounded rectangle over an existing image in ImageMagick v6

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, alpha-transparency

It is straightforward to draw a filled rounded rectangle in ImageMagick v6:

`convert -size 800x600 xc:transparent -fill white -stroke black -strokewidth 20 -draw "roundRectangle 50,100,600,500 32,33" output.png`

But how do you draw a rounded rectangle with transparent fill over an existing image? (Only drawing the outside borders, no filling of the insides.)

Input image:
[image]

Desired output image:
[image]

Comment: I do not understand. Are you trying to make the corners transparent or the inside of the round rectangle or both. What is some stuff? Is that text or an image or what. Please be more specific. If you want a round rectangle on transparency, then create a transparent image and then draw and opaque round rectangle on it and add some opaque text to it. Please post an actual example of what you want. Is this what you want? https://imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want a rounded black rectangle on transparency. That's it. It should be a PNG image, with only black pixels and transparent pixels. The black pixels are arranged in a rounded rectangle shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to draw round rectangle on transparency in Imagemagick 6. The draw command has 3 arguments: top-left corner, bottom-right corner, corner radii.

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:transparent -fill transparent -stroke black -strokewidth 10 -draw "roundrectangle 100,100 399,399 30,30" roundrectangle.png
```

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#primitives

Answer (score 0):

*Use imagemagick and differentiate between inner and outer corners:*

```
magick input.png +write mpr:input ( +clone -alpha off -fill black -colorize 100 -fill white -draw "roundRectangle 64,71 663,504 28,28" -fill black -draw "roundRectangle 83,92 641,484 8,8" ) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite mpr:input -compose over -composite output.png
```

[image]

---

***Update in July 5 2022 AM:***

```
magick input.png +write mpr:input( mpr:input -alpha off -threshold 101% -fill white -draw "roundRectangle 64,72 660,502 26,26" -fill black -draw "roundRectangle 84,92 640,482 6,6" ) -channel-fx "| gray=>alpha" mpr:input -compose over -composite output.png
```

[image]